# How to create a Python Decimal, Binary, Octal and HexaDecimal Converter with MENU?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm very new to this, please bear with me.
I'm trying to design a converter with a menu which allows the user to choose which data type is being used (from and to) for converting (for example) Binary to Decimal (and vice versa) and I'm struggling.
Any help will be much appreciated.

So far, when I run the programme the code executes and displays the menu asking what I want to convert from but that's about as far as I am able to grasp it at the moment.

Here is the code I've done so far....

```
    # introductory menu
    print ("What are you converting from?");

def menu ():
    print ("\n1. Decimal")
    print ("2. Binary")
    print ("3. Octal")
    print ("4. Hexadecimal")
    print ("5. Exit")
    pick = int(input("Please enter an option: "))
    return pick

def toBinary (b):
    return bin(b)

def toDecimal (d):
    return int(d)

def toOctal (o):
    return oct(o)

def toHexadecimal (h):
    return hex(h)


def main():
    choice=menu()
    while choice !=5:
        if choice == 1:
            #convert Decimal to ?
            d = eval(input("What is your Decimal Value?: "))
            print(int(toDecimal (d)))

        elif choice == 2:
            #convert Binary to ?
            b = eval(input("What is your Binary Value?: "))
            print(str(toBinary (b)))

        elif choice == 3:
            #convert Octal to ?
            o = eval(input("What is your Octal Value?: "))
            print(str(toOctal (o)))

        elif choice == 4:
            #convert Hexadecimal to ?
            h = eval(input("What is your Hexadecimal Value?: "))
            print(str(toHexadecimal (h)))

        else:
            print ("Whoops!!! That is an Invalid Entry")

main()
```

Here is a screenshot of the programme running.

As you can see, it's not doing what I really want it to do.

[Screenshot of programme running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbptO.png)

Comment: Where is your code that asks the user to choose the format to convert to? Is there some problem that stops you from writing that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your menu() method inside the while loop, otherwise the choice value will always be the same and never change from 2 (as in the screenshoot you shared).

```
  choice=0
  while choice !=5:
        choice=menu()
```

Furthermore, if you want your tranform program to work properly you need to add another method to select the way you want to transform the input value:

```
def transform_to(value):
    print("Transform to ")
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        print(int(toDecimal (value)))
        choice=5

    elif choice == 2:
        print(str(toBinary (value)))
        choice=5


    elif choice == 3:
        print(str(toOctal (value)))
        choice=5

    elif choice == 4:
        print(str(toHexadecimal (value)))
        choice=5
```

So your final script would be:

```
# introductory menu
print ("What are you converting from?");

def menu ():
    print ("\n1. Decimal")
    print ("2. Binary")
    print ("3. Octal")
    print ("4. Hexadecimal")
    print ("5. Exit")
    pick = int(input("Please enter an option: "))
    return pick

def toBinary (b):
    return bin(b)

def toDecimal (d):
    return int(d)

def toOctal (o):
    return oct(o)

def toHexadecimal (h):
    return hex(h)


def transform_to(value):
    print("Transform to ")
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        print(int(toDecimal (value)))
        choice=5

    elif choice == 2:
        print(str(toBinary (value)))
        choice=5


    elif choice == 3:
        print(str(toOctal (value)))
        choice=5

    elif choice == 4:
        print(str(toHexadecimal (value)))
        choice=5

def main():
    choice=0
    while choice !=5:
        choice=menu()
        if choice == 1:
            #convert Decimal to ?
            d = eval(input("What is your Decimal Value?: "))
            transform_to(d)
            print(int(toDecimal (d)))

        elif choice == 2:
            #convert Binary to ?
            b = eval(input("What is your Binary Value?: "))
            transform_to(b)


        elif choice == 3:
            #convert Octal to ?
            o = eval(input("What is your Octal Value?: "))
            transform_to(o)


        elif choice == 4:
            #convert Hexadecimal to ?
            h = eval(input("What is your Hexadecimal Value?: "))
            transform_to(h)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. I'm very new to coding and getting stuck is one of life's consequences when you're a novice. I've made a few modifications to suit what I'm trying to do. This has been excellent help. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Just for you to know, once a question is solved you have to select the answer as correct answer (the tick icon besides de comment) so people can see the question was solved.